# Applying for a job in a new state, what preparations should I make during/after accepting an offer

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, new-job, relocation

I recently decided to send my resume out to a couple of my "dream" jobs. One has responded so far, and after a great first call, I am scheduled to speak with their hiring manager in the coming days. I still have to successfully complete that interview, and any additional interviews. I am however extremely confident, and am coming to terms with the fact that I may really get my dream job.

It's in a state 9 hours away. I am currently in an apartment lease.

Here are my questions:

*How much time should I ask for before my start date?*

*Are there any financial opportunities available to offset the cost of prematurely ending my lease?* One would be writing off moving expenses on my taxes. I am planning on asking about relocation assistance too.

*Are there any "gotchas" that commonly and unexpectedly occur in this type of event?*

*If you have done this sort of thing, is there anything you would do differently next time?*

Comment: Hey lostPixels. To possibly get this post reopened, I suggest editing to focus more a deeper question. Right now, your question is way too broad, asking for gotchas and experiences. Instead, think about what problem you're *really* trying to solve. What problem would this information help you with? Once you know that problem, [edit] your post to focus on that instead and we can look at possibly allowing more answers. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 5):

First, the **Big Gotcha**:  Get the job offer in writing from someone who is authorized to make it.  Most companies are fine, but you don't want to be "the one" that got burned.  Don't shut anything down before you have that offer.

Second - The amount of time to ask for is entirely up to you.  4 weeks might be enough for most people to move, but it depends on your situation.  Can you pack up everything you own in 4 suitcases and be gone in an afternoon, or do you need 2 moving trucks?  You say you're in an apartment.  Most of the time there is a proviso for breaking the lease.  It is reasonable to ask for assistance on that, if you're not going to have huge moving expenses.

Third - seriously consider selling your non-heirloom furniture on CraigsList or the like rather than trucking it across the country.  It really isn't fun to spend $1000 on a truck, another $300 on fuel, and a long day's drive to keep $800 worth of furniture that you could replace when you got there.  When I was young, I traveled light.  I could get my entire life in my pickup and a U-Haul trailer in an afternoon.  I miss those days, sometimes.

I did make this type of move, once, about 15 years ago.  Looking back, I offer you this advice:  Get the job offer in writing.  I did have the job, but the pay had dropped when I got there.  The paperwork given to me on day 1 had a pay rate 8% lower than what I was told verbally.  In the end, it was fine, as I was promoted twice and made pretty good bank after all that.  I was stupid, but lucky.

Comment: +100 for the Big Gotcha - I've been "the one", and it is 99% less cool than The Matrix makes it sound :) Seriously though, accept nothing short of a written, official job offer AND confirmation that you are hired. The alternative sucks more than I could possibly begin to accurately convey in words; it's natural to just be so damn excited you finally got your "dream job" that you just figure it'll work out, but dot all the i's and cross all the t's because it can take years to recover from one bad experience.

Comment: Check the lease as you may not owe anything for leaving early when reuired to wmove for work. That is common here where I live becasue there are a lot of military people, don't know how common the provision is in other place. You can negotiate for moving expenses, but you will probably have to pay them upfront and get reimbursed if they give them to you.

Answer (score 1):

Wesley Long is right about the Big Gotcha. Be warned. You just had a phone call. It means nothing. Only the written offer counts.

I am not sure what's the company which will offer you the dream job. Is it a big one? A small to medium one? If it's a small company, you can ignore what I have to say below.

If it's a big company, don't worry about the move. Big companies usually have relocation departments. They will arrange for the moving. All you have to do is to follow the instructions from them. Different companies may have different policies. Your questions about the moving will be answered by the relocation department staffs.

I retired from a big company. I was relocated five(5) times. Never had big trouble. I always had little issues such as broken china. They had insurance for that.

As the tax, my employer paid for all the moving expenses. I never had to worry about it.

The only thing you need to think right now is, when are you able to start your new job when you receive the offer? You did not give enough info in your question for me to answer that. I would say anywhere between 2 to 4 weeks.